# PHPExcel не правильный порядок ячеек при чтении xlsx файла

Tags: php, phpexcel

Есть файл xlsx https://yadi.sk/i/do8Zu9T8lAiwAw

При его чтении смещается порядок ячеек, в чем может быть проблема?

Похоже что из-за пустых ячеек что-то.

```
$excel_reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");
$excel_reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $excel_reader->load("wait.xlsx");
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
echo '<table>' . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    echo '<tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(FALSE);
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        echo '<td>' .
             $cell->getValue() .
             '</td>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Выводит следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в excel выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

За решение проблемы небольшое вознаграждение.

PHP 5.6

Comment: Раз уж ковыряетесь с этим кодом, то лучше сразу дропнуть PHPExcel и перейти на PhpSpreadsheet, как рекомендуют в документации: "The project has not be maintained for years and must not be used anymore. All users must migrate to its direct successor PhpSpreadsheet, or another alternative."

Comment: PhpSpreadsheet не читает этот файл.